# Can you specify an accout to use with Google's “.new” doc creation URL?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-docs

I am usually logged in to multiple Google accounts, and I have been using links like these to create sheets (docs, etc.) in the respective accounts:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets**/u/0**/create
- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets**/u/1**/create

There is now a [fancy new way](https://twitter.com/googledocs/status/1055490445088903168) to [create Google docs](https://qz.com/work/1441913/a-new-trick-for-starting-google-docs-slides-sheets-and-forms/) with `.new`:

- Docs: doc.new, docs.new, document.new
- Forms: form.new, forms.new
- Sheets: sheet.new, sheets.new, spreadsheet.new
- Sites: site.new, sites.new, website.new
- Slides: slides.new, deck.new, presentation.new

I'd like to use those shorter URLs, but I need to be able to specify an account. I've tried a few variations, but they haven't worked:

- sheet.new/1
- sheet.new/u/1
- sheet.new/u/1/

So is there any way to use the `.new` shortcut URLs to create new Google docs, and specify which account to create them with?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Jul. 25th 2019 it's actually possible to specify in which account to create the new file, exactly as you stated in your question.

From now on:

- docs.new/1 - creates the file in your personal account
- docs.new/2 - creates the file in your second account (if you're signed in)

That applies to all `.new` shortcut URLs, check the [explainer video from Google](https://twitter.com/gsuite/status/1154421083690405890).

Comment: Oh good! Annoying that `.new/1` = `/u/0/`, but at least there's something.

Answer (score 2):

The "Fancy new" .new shortcuts are just redirecting urls. They only work with the active Google user currently signed in with the browser that is making the request. There is no way to change this currently.

If you use chrome, the best practical solution is to have a seperate user profile for each user.

Comment: Run totally separate browser profiles just to make the `.new` URLs work? I don't think anybody's that dedicated to shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as of Sept 2021 Google still isn't consistent with its URL structure between primary and shortcut domains.

e.g `docs.new/1` will redirect you to a new document under `https://docs.google.com/u/0`

To create new Google Docs for the second logged in user i.e `/u/1` you'd need to use:

- https://docs.new/2
- https://doc.new/2
- https://document.new/2

Ditto for Google Sheets:

- https://sheets.new/2
- https://sheet.new/2
- https://spreadsheet.new/2

And Google Slides:

- https://slides.new/2
- https://slide.new/2
- https://presentation.new/2

Finally for Google Forms:

- https://forms.new/2
- https://form.new/2

Answer (score 0):

I create a folder on my bookmarks bar that has several links. I can then create personal or business documents and spreadsheets with a single click.

- Personal - new doc
- Personal - new sheet
- Business - new doc
- Business - new sheet
- etc.

It uses the URLs from your question, that include the /u/0 and /u/1 componets.

Comment: Better hope you always log in in the same order